# what does <a href="#!"> do?

Tags: html

I've come across the following links:

```
<a href="#!">

<a href="#!" class="mob-trigger" data-target="#mob-commercial">
```

In relation to the href, what does the addition of the exclamation mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice in the code you asked about that you also have the `data-target="#mob-commercial"`.

So what is happening? the `href="#!"` is used as a hack to call a javascript function that uses the `data-target` attribute when pressed on the `<a>` tag instead of the `<button>` tag which is usually used.

Comment: So technically no need for the exclamation mark, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it means "Link to the element with `id="!"`. You can see it working in [this demo](http://jsbin.com/vosame/1/edit?html,output).

In practise, it is probably being used as a hack to have a link without actually linking to anything, so that JavaScript can be bound to it. It should probably be replaced with a `<button type="button">`.